# Parsing data have blank array field showing

Tags: c#, parsing

I am parsing my data output, however, my data has return charicters in it (\n). So when I run my code, the array is built and one of the arrays (4) is blank data... I have tried using null, "", and " ". Would anyone know how I can prevent that last array from showing?

```
        char[] returnChar= {'\n' };
        string parseText = captcha;
        string[] words = parseText.Split(returnChar);
        int count = words.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (words[i] == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This row is empty: " + i);
            }
                MessageBox.Show(words[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx), define the second parameter - [StringSplitOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx).

```
string[] words = 
    parseText.Split(returnChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This way it will skip over empty elements.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean like a trim?

Comment: Oh, you ROCK! Thanks for your help! Excellent answer, I tried it and it worked! 7min till I can accept your answer